# Matlab: Create a zero matrix with 1 in a particular place

Tags: matlab

For example, I can create a `zeros(100)`. But I want the entry of row 58 and column 59 to be 1. But I need temporary variable and multiple lines to do this.

a. Let this matrix be `M`. How can I do this in one line? `M = ....`?

---

P.S.

b. Better still, sometimes I want two or more entries of the zero matrix be 1. 
 Again, how can I do this?

If I can do a. in one-line, of course I can add them up. But is there any special function to do fill zero matrix entries with 1?

Comment: M(58,59) = 1 .... wouldnt this work ?

Comment: What is wrong with using two commands? `M=zeros(100,100)` and then `M(58,59) = 1`?

Comment: for your second part M(M==0) = 1 would work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, remember that a one line expression isn't always the most effective. It could also be harder to read/understand.

One way to do this is by using a [sparse](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix

The following example creates a 10x10 zero-matrix with ones at [5,2] (row 5, col 2) and [7 5]

```
full(sparse([5 7],[2 5],1,10,10))
```

Use `full` to convert it from a sparse matrix to a "full" one

---

Another (faster but maybe not as intuitive) alternative is to use `accumarray`

```
accumarray([5 2;7 5],1,[10,10])
```

Remember that the index values above is used directly in the expression to get on one line, the better option would be to create them separately

```
points = [5 2; 7 5]
```

or perhaps,

```
rowIdx = [5 7];
colIdx = [2 5];
```

Comment: @kww if this answers your question you should consider accepting it as such. Serially asking questions and not accepting answers is not the best way to use SO.